# My gear switches out of Drive and into neutral while driving automatically

Tags: gears

I was wondering what might be the problem with my gear. Sorry, my terminology is bad I'm not a car enthusiast. Anyways, when I first turn on the car, I feel a little tension in the gear when I pull down from park and into drive. The tension is felt as I move the gear past neutral into drive. What I've been doing is pulling down to #2 and then pushing it back into drive. If I drive it for a bit then it'll just slip into neutral even though the gear says it is in drive. Then I have to tug on the gear just a tab and it goes back into drive.

Comment: Welcome to the site: could you add the specific make and model of your car to the question body?  That might help us be more specific in our advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A loose or broken motor mount can cause your symptoms. The motor mounts limit the movement, isolates the vibration and maintains the position of the motor in relation to the chassis. A worn or broken mount can allow the motor to move out of the correct alignment and cause the shift linkage or cable to shift the transmission as the engine moves beyond the normal limits. This engine torque or twisting and the resulting engine movement is most prevalent during acceleration or deacceleration.